# OpenSSL: perform en-/decryption without SSL_read() / SSL_write()

Tags: c, network-programming, openssl

I've written an event-based networking library in C and now I want to add SSL/TLS support via OpenSSL. Instead of using `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()`, I'd rather like to have OpenSSL only perform the encryption/decryption of outgoing/incoming data, letting me transmit/receive the data myself.

I'm new to SSL/TLS and OpenSSL, so:

Is there a way to have OpenSSL *only* perform encryption/decryption of `char` arrays?

Something like `size_t SSL_encrypt(const char *buf_in, size_t size_in, char *buf_out)` would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exactly what you've asked for isn't possible, because with TLS there isn't a 1-to-1 correspondence between sending something at the application layer and sending something on the network socket.  Events like renegotiations mean that sometimes SSL needs to read data from the network in order to make progress sending data, and vice-versa.

However, you can still use OpenSSL to perform SSL but take care of the reading and writing from the network yourself.  You do this by calling `SSL_set_bio()` on the `SSL` pointer instead of `SSL_set_fd()`:

1. Use [`BIO_new_bio_pair()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_bio.html#) to create a connected BIO pair.  One BIO will be read from and written to by the SSL routines, and the other BIO will be read from and written to by your application (allowing it to pass the data to the other end by whatever method it desires).
2. Use [`SSL_set_bio()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_set_bio.html#) on a new SSL object to set both the read and write BIO to one of the BIOs in the pair generated.
3. Use `BIO_read()` and `BIO_write()` on the other BIO in the pair to read and write the SSL protocol data.
4. Use `SSL_accept()`, `SSL_connect()`, `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` as normal on the SSL object.

(It's not clear what advantage this would give in your application, though: in this case you can't really do anything other than read and write exactly what OpenSSL passes you, so you might as well let it do the reading and writing too).

Comment: Thanks a lot caf, it's the first time I get an understandable explanation of how the BIOs are supposed to be used! Adding +1 for this!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same and could not find any documentation, so digged into OpenSSL code. Looks like it is trivial to do with `BIO`s, as they are basically objects with function pointers to read/write and similar functions that we want to replace. Main struct of interest is `bio_method_st`, sadly OpenSSL only defines it only internally.

In the below code, I copy relevant definition and provide my own write function.

Where you would normally call

```
SSL_set_fd(ssl, clientfd);
```

instead do:

```
// Provide definitions for some openssl internal structs
struct BIO_MSG;
struct bio_method_st {
    int type;
    char *name;
    int (*bwrite) (BIO *, const char *, size_t, size_t *);
    int (*bwrite_old) (BIO *, const char *, int);
    int (*bread) (BIO *, char *, size_t, size_t *);
    int (*bread_old) (BIO *, char *, int);
    int (*bputs) (BIO *, const char *);
    int (*bgets) (BIO *, char *, int);
    long (*ctrl) (BIO *, int, long, void *);
    int (*create) (BIO *);
    int (*destroy) (BIO *);
    long (*callback_ctrl) (BIO *, int, BIO_info_cb *);
    int (*bsendmmsg) (BIO *, BIO_MSG *, size_t, size_t, uint64_t, size_t *);
    int (*brecvmmsg) (BIO *, BIO_MSG *, size_t, size_t, uint64_t, size_t *);
};

// Get methods for 'socket'
const BIO_METHOD *methods = BIO_s_socket();

// Clone them
BIO_METHOD *my_methods = (BIO_METHOD*)malloc(sizeof(bio_method_st));
memcpy(my_methods, methods, sizeof(bio_method_st));

// Replace the ones where you want to provide your own definition
((bio_method_st*)my_methods)->bwrite = [](BIO *bio, const char *data, size_t size, size_t *written) -> int
{
    int fd = BIO_get_fd(bio, nullptr); // Get original fd from the BIO object
    ssize_t res = write(fd, data, size);

    // Return data in the way openssl wants
    if (res > 0)
    {
        *written = res;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *written = 0;
        return res;
    }
};

// Create new BIO with our methods
BIO *bio = BIO_new(my_methods);
BIO_set_fd(bio, clientfd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
```

Note: since this depends on internal OpenSSL layout, any OpenSSL version change etc might break your code, so use it with care.