# Reading/writing encrypted data using file descriptors with OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, network-programming

I'm not sure if this is a common way of interfacing with OpenSSL or not, but I can't really find any examples or references to trying to do it this way.

I have some applications that interfact with a number of things using file descriptors (nothing fancy here). This works great for plain text TCP sockets, for example: you can just read/write using normal standard library functions. I've used `SSL_write` and `SSL_read` before to read/write from encrypted connections, but I find this very clunky. The objective is handling I/O for things that could either be encrypted or not, and handling them in the same way. With the above, you have to pass around both `SSL *ssl` for encrypted connections and then a normal file descriptor for unencrypted connections, and depending on whether it's encrypted or not, use the right I/O functions, not all of which even have an SSL equivalent.

For example, the following macros illustrate this:

```
#ifdef HAVE_SSL_RECV
#define my_recv(ssl, fd, buf, len, flags) (ssl ? SSL_recv(ssl, buf, len, flags) : recv(fd, buf, len, flags)
#endif
#define my_read(ssl, fd, buf, len) (ssl ? SSL_read(ssl, buf, len) : read(fd, buf, len))
#define my_write(ssl, fd, buf, len) (ssl ? SSL_write(ssl, buf, len) : write(fd, buf, len))
```

What I would like to do is just have a file descriptor referring to the decrypted side of the SSL connection, such that anything written to or read from that file descriptor is encrypted/decrypted as you would expect with using `SSL_read` and `SSL_write`. What I'm on unclear on is if there is any builtin or standard way of doing this.

This related question (kind of but not quite) suggested BIO pairs: [OpenSSL: perform en-/decryption without SSL_read() / SSL_write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030661/openssl-perform-en-decryption-without-ssl-read-ssl-write)

However, reading the man page for those (https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BIO_s_bio.html), I don't think this is quite what I want, since BIO pairs do buffering and that's not what I need at all here.

Most similar types of interfaces that I've used provide a way to get a file descriptor that you can use in your program, and OpenSSL does have `SSL_get_wfd` and `SSL_get_rfd`, which I assumed would be what I was looking for, but it seems these are actually the raw socket file descriptor itself, exactly the same thing as the file descriptor passed to `SSL_set_fd` in the first place! (Confirmed by printing out all 3 file descriptors). So I'm not even sure what the point of these functions are in the first place, they don't provide any new information.

Obviously, I could use do this manually, by creating a pipe and then using one end of the pipe as my file descriptor for reading/writing and then spawn another thread to read/write from it and relay to the appropriate SSL functions, appropriately abstracting away that the connection is using TLS. But, is there a better or more standard way of doing this, and a way to avoid the overhead of additional threads for each SSL connection? (If not, that's fine, but I wanted to be sure before I went with that approach.)

Comment: As a file descriptor is for a relatively low level interface using a somewhat higher abstraction like a pipe *does* seem to be the correct way to go. I mean, there is no technical difference to a lower level API between a file descriptor of a plaintext or encrypted file.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow the difference, since pipe returns file descriptors, but yes, that's the initial solution I had in mind. I implemented this in the meantime, and it works fine - I'm using a single thread to poll all 2N+1 file descriptors (for N SSL connections + a control pipe), so hopefully relatively small overhead... just curious if there was a better approach with OpenSSL